# Greek booktitle in bibtex

Tags: bibtex, greek

I have .bib files going back 30+ years, so still use Bibtex and the "traditional" commands for accented letters (e.g., `\'{e}` and so on).  I have tried Biber etc. and find it (a) a great deal of work to get from what I have to what I need and (b) somewhat confusing.

I have a small number of book titles (two, to be precise) which have a Greek title in an otherwise Roman-alphabet bibliographic entry.  What would be the easiest way to create a bibtex entry for these?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the book titles writting in polytonic Greek? Which font are you using? Do you use pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, or LuaLaTeX to compile your document? Are the authors' names also written in Greek, or just the `title` fields?

Comment: I use pdfLaTeX.  The main text is usually in Computer Modern Roman.  I've not had to use  Greek before (apart from maths which is not the same!) so will take advice as to the font.  The Greek portions are literally just parts of the titles.  It is Classicists being pretentious -- one has a subtitle in Latin!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on how you handle Greek in your document in general, and mentioned in the comments. However, assuming a 'classical' setup with `LGR` font encoding for Greek and compiling with pdfLaTeX, you can use that in the bibliography in the same way as in the document itself. In the MWE below a macro `\textgreek` is defined to automate the selection of the LGR encoding and limiting it to the argument of the macro.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{greekbk,
   title = {\textgreek{Βίος και Πολιτεία του Αλέξη Ζορμπά}},
   author = {\textgreek{Νίκος Καζαντζάκης}},
   year = {1946}
}
@book{englishbk,
   title = {The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark},
   author = {William Shakespeare},
   year = {1601}
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\textgreek}[1]{\begingroup\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont#1\endgroup}
\begin{document}
This is a document that cites publications in two alphabets: \cite{greekbk,englishbk}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on the biblatex/biber side:

biblatex can read bibtex output, so moving to biblatex is minimal. Default style is numeric.

[image: bibtex]

MWE

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{greekbk,
   title = {\textgreek{Βίος και Πολιτεία του Αλέξη Ζορμπά}},
   author = {\textgreek{Νίκος Καζαντζάκης}},
   year = {1946},
}
@book{englishbk,
   title = {The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark},
   author = {William Shakespeare},
   year = {1601},
}   
@book{rus,
   title = {Грек Зорба},
   author = {Никос Казандзакис},
   year = {2003},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\textgreek}[1]{\begingroup\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont#1\endgroup}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}



\begin{document}
This is a document that cites publications in two alphabets: \cite{greekbk,englishbk}.%, rus, esp, zh}.

Compile with pdflatex.

\printbibliography[title={References (biblatex/bibtex + legacy fonts)}]
\end{document}
```

Sorted cites option; biber is the default backend:

[image: biber]

MWE

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: biber
% arara: pdflatex

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{greekbk,
   title = {\textgreek{Βίος και Πολιτεία του Αλέξη Ζορμπά}},
   author = {\textgreek{Νίκος} \textgreek{Καζαντζάκης}},
   year = {1946},
}
@book{englishbk,
   title = {The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark},
   author = {William Shakespeare},
   year = {1601},
}   
@book{rus,
   title = {Грек Зорба},
   author = {Никос Казандзакис},
   year = {2003},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand{\textgreek}[1]{\begingroup\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont#1\endgroup}

\usepackage[sortcites=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}



\begin{document}
This is a document that cites publications in two alphabets: \cite{greekbk,englishbk}%, rus, esp, zh}.

Compile with pdflatex.

\printbibliography[title={References (biblatex/biber + legacy fonts)}]
\end{document}
```

Swapping to truetype Unicode fonts; and author-year style:

[image: Unicode fonts]

MWE

```
% arara: lualatex
% arara: biber
% arara: lualatex

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{greekbk,
   title = {Βίος και Πολιτεία του Αλέξη Ζορμπά},
   author = {Νίκος Καζαντζάκης},
   year = {1946},
}
@book{englishbk,
   title = {The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark},
   author = {William Shakespeare},
   year = {1601},
}   
@book{rus,
   title = {Грек Зорба},
   author = {Никос Казандзакис},
   year = {2003},
}
@book{esp,
   title = {Zorba, el griego},
   author = {Nikos Kazantzakis},
   translator = {Jaime Berenguer Amenós},
   year = {1972},
}
@book{zh,
   title = {{\fchinese 希臘左巴}},
   author = {{\fchinese 卡山札基}},
   year = {1946},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}%has Greek and Latin

\newfontfamily\fchinese{Noto Serif CJK SC}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,
%%backend=bibtex,
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}



\begin{document}
This is a document that cites publications in two alphabets: \cite{greekbk,englishbk,rus,esp,zh}.

Compile with lualatex.

\printbibliography[title={References (biblatex/biber + ttf/otf fonts)}]
\end{document}
```

Letting polyglossia handle the fonts (Chinese is done by hand):

[image: polyglossia]

MWE

```
% arara: lualatex
% arara: biber
% arara: lualatex

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{greekbk,
   title = {Βίος και Πολιτεία του Αλέξη Ζορμπά},
   author = {Νίκος Καζαντζάκης},
   year = {1946},
   langid={greek},
}
@book{englishbk,
   title = {The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark},
   author = {William Shakespeare},
   year = {1601},
}   
@book{rus,
   title = {Грек Зорба},
   author = {Никос Казандзакис},
   year = {2003},
   langid={russian},
}
@book{esp,
   title = {Zorba, el griego},
   author = {Nikos Kazantzakis},
   translator = {Jaime Berenguer Amenós},
   year = {1972},
   langid={spanish},   
}
@book{zh,
   title = {{\fchinese 希臘左巴}},
   author = {{\fchinese 卡山札基}},
   year = {1946},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}%has Greek and Latin
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{spanish}
\setotherlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{russian}
\newfontfamily\spanishfont{DejaVu Serif}
\newfontfamily\greekfont{Liberation Serif}
\newfontfamily\russianfont{EB Garamond}
\newfontfamily\fchinese{Noto Serif CJK SC}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,
language=auto,
autolang=other,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}



\begin{document}
This is a document that cites publications in two alphabets: \cite{greekbk,englishbk,rus,esp,zh}.

Compile with lualatex.

\printbibliography[title={References (biblatex/biber + polyglossia)}]
\end{document}
```

Just to highlight that they are different font/script environments:

[image: font-level settings]

MWE

```
% arara: lualatex
% arara: biber
% arara: lualatex

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{greekbk,
   title = {Βίος και Πολιτεία του Αλέξη Ζορμπά},
   author = {Νίκος Καζαντζάκης},
   year = {1946},
   langid={greek},
   langidopts={variant=mono},
}
@book{englishbk,
   title = {The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark},
   author = {William Shakespeare},
   year = {1601},
}   
@book{rus,
   title = {Грек Зорба},
   author = {Никос Казандзакис},
   year = {2003},
   langid={russian},
}
@book{esp,
   title = {Zorba, el griego},
   author = {Nikos Kazantzakis},
   translator = {Jaime Berenguer Amenós},
   year = {1972},
   langid={spanish},   
}
@book{zh,
   title = {{\fchinese 希臘左巴}},
   author = {{\fchinese 卡山札基}},
   year = {1946},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\setmainlanguage{english}
\newfontfamily{\spanishfont}[Color=red]{DejaVu Serif}
\newfontfamily{\greekfont}[Script=Greek,Colour=blue]{Liberation Serif}
\newfontfamily\russianfont[Script=Cyrillic,Colour=brown]{EB Garamond}

\setotherlanguage{spanish}
\setotherlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{russian}
\newfontfamily\fchinese{Noto Serif CJK SC}[Scale=1.5]
\usepackage[style=authoryear,
language=auto,
autolang=other,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}



\begin{document}
This is a document that cites publications in two alphabets: \cite{greekbk,englishbk,rus,esp,zh}.

Compile with lualatex.

\printbibliography[title={References (biblatex/biber + polyglossia)}]
\end{document}
```

Fonts in harmony; and back to numeric:

[image: all done]

MWE

```
% arara: lualatex
% arara: biber
% arara: lualatex

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{greekbk,
   title = {Βίος και Πολιτεία του Αλέξη Ζορμπά},
   author = {Νίκος Καζαντζάκης},
   year = {1946},
   langid={greek},
}
@book{englishbk,
   title = {The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark},
   author = {William Shakespeare},
   year = {1601},
}   
@book{rus,
   title = {Грек Зорба},
   author = {Никос Казандзакис},
   year = {2003},
   langid={russian},
}
@book{esp,
   title = {Zorba, el griego},
   author = {Nikos Kazantzakis},
   translator = {Jaime Berenguer Amenós},
   year = {1972},
   langid={spanish},   
}
@book{zh,
   title = {{\fchinese 希臘左巴}},
   author = {{\fchinese 卡山札基}},
   year = {1946},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}%has Greek and Latin
\setmainlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage{spanish}
\setotherlanguage{greek}
\setotherlanguage{russian}
\newfontfamily\spanishfont{Noto Serif}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek]{Noto Serif}
\newfontfamily\russianfont[Script=Cyrillic]{Noto Serif}
\newfontfamily\fchinese{Noto Serif CJK SC}
\usepackage[sortcites=true,
language=auto,
autolang=other,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}



\begin{document}
This is a document that cites publications in two alphabets: \cite{greekbk,englishbk,rus,esp,zh}.

Compile with lualatex.

\printbibliography[title={References (biblatex/biber + polyglossia)}]
\end{document}
```

Using babel for the fonts (Chinese is done by hand):

[image: babel]

MWE

```
% arara: lualatex
% arara: biber
% arara: lualatex

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{greekbk,
   title = {Βίος και Πολιτεία του Αλέξη Ζορμπά},
   author = {Νίκος Καζαντζάκης},
   year = {1946},
   langid={greek},
}
@book{englishbk,
   title = {The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark},
   author = {William Shakespeare},
   year = {1601},
}   
@book{rus,
   title = {Грек Зорба},
   author = {Никос Казандзакис},
   year = {2003},
   langid={russian},
}
@book{esp,
   title = {Zorba, el griego},
   author = {Nikos Kazantzakis},
   translator = {Jaime Berenguer Amenós},
   year = {1972},
   langid={spanish},   
}
@book{zh,
   title = {{\fchinese 希臘左巴}},
   author = {{\fchinese 卡山札基}},
   year = {1946},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}%has Greek and Latin
\usepackage[spanish,greek,russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\babelfont[spanish]{rm}{Noto Serif}
\babelfont[greek]{rm}{Noto Serif}
\babelfont[russian]{rm}{Noto Serif}
\newfontfamily\fchinese{Noto Serif CJK SC}
\usepackage[sortcites=true,
language=auto,
autolang=other,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}



\begin{document}
This is a document that cites publications in two alphabets: \cite{greekbk,englishbk,rus,esp,zh}.

Compile with lualatex.

\printbibliography[title={References (biblatex/biber + babel)}]
\end{document}
```

And babel doing Chinese as well:

[image: babel chinese]

MWE

```
% arara: lualatex
% arara: biber
% arara: lualatex

\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{greekbk,
   title = {Βίος και Πολιτεία του Αλέξη Ζορμπά},
   author = {Νίκος Καζαντζάκης},
   year = {1946},
   langid={greek},
}
@book{englishbk,
   title = {The Tragedy of Hamlet, Prince of Denmark},
   author = {William Shakespeare},
   year = {1601},
}   
@book{rus,
   title = {Грек Зорба},
   author = {Никос Казандзакис},
   year = {2003},
   langid={russian},
}
@book{esp,
   title = {Zorba, el griego},
   author = {Nikos Kazantzakis},
   translator = {Jaime Berenguer Amenós},
   year = {1972},
   langid={spanish},   
}
@book{zh,
   title = {希臘左巴},
   author = {卡山札基},
   year = {1946},
   langid={chinese},   
}

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Serif}%has Greek and Latin
\usepackage[spanish,greek,russian,english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\babelfont[spanish]{rm}{Noto Serif}
\babelfont[greek]{rm}{Noto Serif}
\babelfont[russian]{rm}{Noto Serif}
\babelprovide{chinese}
\babelfont[chinese]{rm}{Noto Serif CJK SC}
%\newfontfamily\fchinese{Noto Serif CJK SC}
\usepackage[sortcites=true,
language=auto,
autolang=other,]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}



\begin{document}
This is a document that cites publications in two alphabets: \cite{greekbk,englishbk,rus,esp,zh}.

Compile with lualatex.

\printbibliography[title={References (biblatex/biber + babel)}]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for this comprehensive set of examples, very useful and will need some careful perusing!